# craft.matrixBlocks - related to entry

Tags: matrix, relatedto

I've got classes by entry and each week is a matrix block inside that week. I'm then outputting all weeks together using this query

```
{% set startDate = date(now)|atom %}

{% set classes = craft.matrixBlocks()
  .type('classDay')
  .fieldId('54')
  .limit('6')
  .classDate(['and', ">= #{startDate}"])
  .orderBy('classDate ASC')
  .all()
%}
```

Which works fine. this is the entire for loop (simplified

```
{% for class in classes %}

{# set the entry that this matrix block comes from #}
{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.id(class.primaryOwnerId).one() %}

<div class="relative duration-300 bg-white shadow-xl swiper-slide hover:scale-105">
  <div class="relative ">

    {% set image = mainEntry.image.one() ?? null %}
    {% if image|length %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="">

    {% if mainEntry.classFormat|length %}
      some code here
    {% endif %}
  </div><!-- /.relative -->
  <div class="p-6 mb-8">
    <p class="mb-2 text-base font-lato text-blueBrand">
      {{ class.classDate|date('l, F d') }}
    </p><!-- /.font-lato text- text-blueBrand -->
    <h3 class="font-merriweather text-[1.3rem]"><a href="{{ mainEntry.url }}">{{ mainEntry.title }}</a></h3>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.slide -->
{% endfor %}
```

This is all in a matrix block of another entry where I'm outputting a slider. Now the client wants to restrict the results to a category chosen in this matrix field. I've set that up but I get errors when I add the following below the main classes query

```
{% set classCats = block.courseCategory.all() %}
{% set classes = classes|merge({ relatedTo:['and', classCats] }) %}
```

The error is:

Key "primaryOwnerId" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.

and references this line of code

```
{# set the entry that this matrix block comes from #}
{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.id(class.primaryOwnerId).one() %}
```

I cannot figure out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `classes` variable isn't an element query when you try to add the `relatedTo` query param using `|merge` – it's an array, because you've already executed the query using `.all()`. The error occurs because your `classes` array now consists of a number of Matrix blocks, plus a regular array containing the `relatedTo` (which is where the error occurs).

To fix the error, make sure to add the [`relatedTo`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter) param as an actual query param, before the query is executed, for example:

```
{# Build base query #}
{% set classesQuery = craft.matrixBlocks()
  .type('classDay')
  .fieldId('54')
  .limit('6')
  .classDate(['and', ">= #{startDate}"])
  .orderBy('classDate ASC')
%}

{# Check for class categories #}
{% set classCats = block.courseCategory.all() %}
{% if classCats %}
    {% do classesQuery.relatedTo(['and'] | merge(classCats)) %}
{% endif %}

{# Execute the query #}
{% set classes = classesQuery.all() %}

{% for class in classes %}
    ...
```

Comment: that stopped the error but now I get no results event though I've manuallly edited entries to ensure that there entries in the category I'm testing.

Comment: Hard to say why; I don't really understand the content model here. It might be due to the `['and'] | merge(classCats)` – in your original code, you had `['and', classCats]`. That syntax doesn't really make sense unless you're [combining multiple relational criteria](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/relations.html#compound-criteria), so I assumed the intent was that each "class" needs to have a relation to *all* the categories defined in `block.courseCategory`. If that's not the case (i.e. each "class" only needs to relate to at least 1 of the categories), you can just do `.relatedTo(classCats)`.